# What type of exercise is optimal for reducing proinflammatory cytokines?

Tags: test-results, weightlifting, cytokines, aerobic, crp-c-reactive-protein

What type of exercise (HIIT, weight lifting, aerobic) is optimal for reducing proinflammatory cytokines (like TNF-alpha) and increasing anti-inflammatory cytokines (like IL-10)?

CRP levels drop with physical activity, but I'm more interested in cytokines, which are not reflected in CRP levels.

Comment: See: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/